# Query processing problems with dbeaver

Tags: mariadb, dbeaver

Just about any sql script I put into dbeaver fails to process correctly where the same scripts run fine in HeidiSQL or SQL Workbench.

example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertSolidMPO`(IN daDeviceID INTEGER, IN daPrefix VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    DECLARE commonPorts VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE common VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE commonIndex INT;
    DECLARE portName VARCHAR(20);

    SET commonPorts = 'ABC'; -- Define the common ports

    SET commonIndex = 1;

    loop_common: LOOP
        SET common = SUBSTRING(commonPorts, commonIndex, 1);

        IF common IS NULL OR common  = '' THEN
            LEAVE loop_common;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO Port (ConnectorType, OwnerCompany, PortName, DeviceID)
        VALUES ('MPO8', 226, CONCAT(daPrefix, '/', common, '-Common'), daDeviceID);

        set commonIndex = commonIndex + 1;
        SET i = 1;

        loop_i: LOOP
            SET portName = CONCAT(daPrefix, '/', common, i);
            -- insert port into Port table
            INSERT INTO Port (ConnectorType, OwnerCompany, PortName, DeviceID)
            VALUES ('LC Duplex', 226, portName, daDeviceID);
            
            SET i = i + 1;
            
            IF i > 4 THEN
                LEAVE loop_i;
            END IF;
        END LOOP loop_i;
    END LOOP loop_common;
END;
```

If I highlight the whole function and click "execute SQL query" `Ctrl+Enter`
it works fine

if I click "execute SQL script" `Alt+X`
I get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Error position: line: 2
```

It looks like it its just assuming each `;` is the end of a command.

If I paste this into HeidiSQL it just runs with no intervention from me.

How can I make dbeaver also work like that?

Comment: Look to use of `DELIMITER` to help get around that issue.